# Direction of action and source of an electromagnetic field in analogy to electric and to magnetic fields

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

For an electric field we need a charge and we can represent the direction of action by drawing field lines. For a magnetic field, we need a magnetic dipole and we can also represent the direction of action by drawing field lines. In the first case a charge is deflected by the field, in the second case a magnetic dipole is rotated.

How can the analogy to the above be made for an electromagnetic field?

A view from the sidelines. The tag "Electromagnetic field" led to "Electromagnetism" and the tag is explained like this: " The classical theory of electric and magnetic fields, both in the static and dynamic case. Also covers general questions about magnets, electric attraction/repulsion etc." No mention of the electromagnetic field. On the other hand we express for example the electromagnetic field strength $F^{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: *For an electric field we need a charge.* No, you don’t. A changing magnetic field suffices. *For a magnetic field, we need a magnetic dipole.* No, you don’t. A current or a changing electric field suffices.

Comment: @Ghoster You are right. Your comment leads me to my real problem of understanding. An EM field is postulated that does not need any sources. Something has taken on a life of its own in physics, which is mathematically OK, but does not hold up in reality. See the last comment on this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/735923/how-em-radiation-propagates/736079#736079). I think I have to ask it in a new question.

Comment: *The classical theory of electric and magnetic fields … No mention of the electromagnetic field.* The electromagnetic field has six components at each point. Three are the electric field and three are the magnetic field. It’s not like the electromagnetic field is some completely different thing. Electromagnetic just means electric-and-magnetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A perfectly valid representation of the electromagnetic field (in some reference frame), is to draw the electric and magnetic field lines. If the field dies off sufficiently fast at asymptotic infinity, then as you said all fields are ultimately generated by the charges and currents. However, as pointed in in the comments, the electric field need not be a simple Coulomb field like you get in electrostatics, since a changing magnetic field can also act as a source for an electric field. (Analogous comments hold for the magnetic field).